# How to look at all functions and variables in memory (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know of a tool that I can drop a bunch of JavaScript into that will list all of the functions and variables contained in the JavaScript? I know I can load JS into Chrome DevTools and FireBug but I want to enumerate all of the currently loaded variables and functions and AFAIK that is not possible with either of those tools.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebug you can use the DOM tab to look at variables and functions. You can also set a break point with the Firebug debugger (on the Script tab) and look at the local scope variables and the function call stack.

Comment: Well then, I shall get started eating my words! Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: @MoarCodePlz Roger that. Also, if you're looking for code completion type stuff for development, Aptana will show your functions and variables as you type: http://www.daveoncode.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/js_javadoc_aptana_2.gif